# cmd+/ shortcut gone

Tags: macos, keyboard

1Password shortcut <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>\</kbd> stopped working on all browsers so I tried to change it to <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>/</kbd> just to try but now I lost <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>/</kbd>!

I tried to reset the keyboard shortcuts to default from the preference page but that didn't help.

How can I get <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>/</kbd> back? (the shortcut to show the main window when no window is showing)

I'm using Lion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need 1Password v3.6.5 or newer to have single keystroke log in to work with Safari 5.1 (Lion or not)

It's on their FAQ - http://help.agilebits.com/1Password3/single_keystroke_login.html

Answer (score 1):

When did it stop working, when you upgraded to Lion, or more recently?  Has the shortcut ever worked for you in Lion?

There is a new Safari Extension for 1Password within Safari in Lion that is different to what has come before, ensure it is installed and check the shortcut again.  Mine works fine, you may have an old plugin installed.  I don;t use other browsers, so cannot comment, but would imagine that they too have an all new plugin for Lion.

CMD / should toggle the status bar on/off at the bottom of your browser window in Safari.

Comment: I saw a similar problem yesterday, installing the latest extension and resetting the keys to the same values worked

Comment: It was intentionally disabled for Safari 5.1 by the developer until they worked out some kinks. The software now restores the functionality of taking this shortcut from Safari if you get [1Password v3.6.5](http://help.agilebits.com/1Password3/single_keystroke_login.html).